# How can I play a video from a Stream object in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

For a while I searched for a way to play a video while it is being decrypted in Flutter, to do this I used the [cryptography](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography) package with it's native FFI counterpart by using the Chacha20 cipher for better performance. Then I searched for a package to play a video from a data stream (a Stream<List<int>> to be more specific) but I couldn't find any known results and I REALLY don't want to do this myself because I am sure it would be slow and would have a TON of bugs. So I tried to fork the video_player plug-in to see if I could at any point implement a stream player but because of the way the video player is implemented, all the data source types are hard-coded, this means that I can almost certainly say that the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) won't work with my stream of data. This is where I am right now.

**TL;DR**: Does someone has an idea of how I could play a video from a stream of data. (a Stream<List<int>>)

**EDIT**:
I have dug deeper into the `video_player` package and I can assure that the `video_player` **does not** support any stream data flow, I have written a message on [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49967#issuecomment-1500935587) that explains why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chewie` package along with the `video_player` package.

```
void _setupChewieController() async {
final videoController = await widget.videoStream.first;
_chewieController = ChewieController(
  videoPlayerController: videoController,
  autoPlay: true,
  looping: true,
  // other ChewieController options...
);
```

}

Comment: This is not what I want, here ``videoStream`` would be a ``Stream<List<int>>`` not a ``Stream<VideoPlayerController>``